# Use 'mapcar' to build a hooks list; "wrong-type-argument listp lambda"

Tags: hooks, use-package, mapping

How can I write a mapping (e.g. a `mapcar` expression) to build the list for a use-package `:hook` clause?

I'm attempting to build the list in this `:hook` expression:

```lisp
(use-package eglot
  :hook (
         (lorem-mode . eglot-ensure)
         (ipsum-mode . eglot-ensure)
         (dolor-mode . eglot-ensure)
         )
  )
```

by replacing the literal list with a `mapcar` expression:

```lisp
(use-package eglot
  :hook
  (mapcar
   (lambda (lang-mode)
     (cons lang-mode '(. eglot-ensure)))
   '(
     lorem-mode
     ipsum-mode
     dolor-mode
     ))
  )
```

When I try evaluating the `mapcar` expression, it returns the list as expected.

> ((lorem-mode . eglot-ensure) (ipsum-mode . eglot-ensure) (dolor-mode . eglot-ensure))

When I try evaluating the entire `use-package` expression, it throws a Lisp error:

> (wrong-type-argument listp lambda)
> […]

(If it's useful to show the entire traceback here I can; though hopefully the mistake I've made is obvious without that?)

How can I map (using `mapcar` or something more appropriate) a literal list of only the mode names, to generate the list-of-lists needed in `:hook`?

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

Comment: Not what you are asking about, but just a tip: `(cons lang-mode '(. eglot-ensure))` is exactly equivalent to `(cons lang-mode 'eglot-ensure)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at the error message: `(wrong-type-argument listp lambda)`. This means that it wanted a list, and it found a compiled lambda function. The reason for this is that `use-package` is a macro, and macros do not evaluate their arguments. This means that you cannot run any code here; you can only supply a literal list.

If you want to reduce the amount of typing that you need to do, you could write it like this instead:

```lisp
(use-package eglot
  :hook ((lorem-mode ipsum-mode dolor-mode) . eglot-ensure))
```

For more information, see [chapter 4.3 Hooks](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/use-package/Hooks.html) of the use-package manual.

Comment: "use-package is a macro, and macros do not evaluate their arguments". Thank you, that clearly explains the difference in behaviour.